# Why do domains that serve ad content show up in ad reports alongside the sites that actually have the ads embedded?

Tags: domains, advertising, reporting, google-dfp, ad-server

I'm trying to understand why when I look at a domain report from an adserver (eg DCM) that I see the following below included alongside normal domains?  Surely I should only see the domains that the ads appear on?

- `adx.g.doubleclick.net`
- `pubads.g.doubleclick.net`
- `googleads.g.doubleclick.net`
- `tpc.googlesyndication.com`
- `s3.amazonaws.com`